# P/Invoke SHSetKnownFolderPath Failing

Tags: windows, powershell, known-folders

I thought this would be a simple enough script. I came across this article about how to use powershell to redirect folders to OneDrive here: https://stealthpuppy.com/onedrive-intune-folder-redirection/

I realized this script would not work for me, as the way it is written it requires user context and cannot be run silently using Task Scheduler, so I set out to try and "rewrite" the script using a system context. All seems to be working except for one chunk that I can't seem to understand. I think it's C# and I'm only familiar with powershell. I am only concerned with redirecting the downloads folder, so his is what I have.

```
#These are the potential GUIDs for the Downloads KFM path of the user
$Guids = $null
$Guids = @()
$Guids += [pscustomobject]@{
        Guid = '{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}'
        Paths = @()
        }
$Guids += [pscustomobject]@{
        Guid = '{7d83ee9b-2244-4e70-b1f5-5393042af1e4}'
        Paths = @()
        }

#Log Variables
$timestamp = Get-Date -Format o | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace ":", "." }
$LogPath = "$env:USERPROFILE\AppData\Local\Intune-PowerShell-Logs\OneDriveSync-$timestamp.txt"

Start-Transcript -Path $LogPath

$CurrentUsers = Get-ItemProperty -path  "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\*" | Where {($_.ProfileImagePath -notmatch '.NET') -and ($_.ProfileImagePath -notmatch 'Default') -and ($_.ProfileImagePath -match "Users")} | select ProfileImagePath,PSChildName

ForEach ($CurrentUser in $CurrentUsers)
{
    $SourcePath = "$($CurrentUser.ProfileImagePath)\Downloads"
    $Targetpath = "$($CurrentUser.ProfileImagePath)\OneDrive\Downloads"
    $Rootpath = "HKU:\$($CurrentUser.PSChildName)"
    $ShellFolderspath = "$RootPath\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders"
    $UserShellFolderspath = "$Rootpath\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders"
    
    #region 1 - Identify registry keys to update
    New-PSDrive -Name HKU -PSProvider Registry -Root HKEY_USERS -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    #Adding Downloads Guids to array
    ForEach ($object in $Guids)
    {
        #Check Shell Folders Path
        If ($Item = Get-ItemProperty $ShellFolderspath -Name $object.Guid -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
        {
        "$($object.guid) found in Shell Folders path"
        $Object.paths += @($Item.PSpath)
        }
        
        #Check User Shell Folders Path
        If ($Item = Get-ItemProperty $UserShellFolderspath -Name $object.Guid -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
        {
        "$($object.guid) found in User Shell Folders path"
        $Object.paths += @($Item.PSpath)
        }
    }
    #endregion
    
#region 2
# Define SHSetKnownFolderPath if it hasn't been defined already
$Type = ([System.Management.Automation.PSTypeName]'KnownFolders').Type
If (-not $Type) 
{
$Signature = @'
[DllImport("shell32.dll")]
public extern static int SHSetKnownFolderPath(ref Guid folderId, uint flags, IntPtr token, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string path);
'@
$Type = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $Signature -Name 'KnownFolders' -Namespace 'SHSetKnownFolderPath' -PassThru
}

#Test if new directory exists
If (!(Test-Path -Path $Targetpath -PathType Container))
{
    New-Item -Path $TargetPath -Type Directory -Force
}
#Validate the path
If (Test-Path $TargetPath -PathType Container) 
{
    #Call SHSetKnownFolderPath
    #return $Type::SHSetKnownFolderPath([ref]$KnownFolders[$KnownFolder], 0, 0, $Path)
    ForEach ($object in $Guids) 
    {
        $result = $Type::SHSetKnownFolderPath([ref]$object.guid, 0, 0, $Targetpath)
        If ($result -ne 0) 
        {
            $errormsg = "Error redirecting $($Object.guid). Return code $($result) = $((New-Object System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception($result)).message)"
            Throw $errormsg
        }
    }
} 
Else 
{
    Throw New-Object System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException "Could not find part of the path $Path."
}

#endregion

#region 3 - Set new downloads directory
ForEach ($Object in $Guids)
{
    ForEach ($path in $object.paths)
    {
        Set-ItemProperty -Path $path -Name $object.Guid -Value $Targetpath -Verbose
    }
}
#endregion

#region 4
#Move files from old directory to the new one
#Robocopy.exe "$SourcePath" "$Targetpath" /E /MOV /XJ /XF *.ini /R:1 /W:1 /NP
#endregion
#}
}
    
    Stop-Transcript
```

All seems to work except that I get an error on line 74 that says,
"Error redirecting {374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}. Return code
-2147024894 = The system cannot find the file specified"

I have spent almost an entire work day trying to tackle this problem and am getting nowhere. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: When I do the `$CurrentUsers = Get-ItemProperty -path  "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\...` command I get back 3 profiles, 2 of which are NOT my active account or even exist as users on my computer anymore.  I'm sure if I ran the script it would error when those extra `$CurrentUser` objects are processed.  Perhaps that is what you are experiencing?

Comment: That's interesting... I only get my active profile, so that doesn't explain the error on my side. My goal was to narrow down any actual user profiles, since some of our machines may have more than one user account and the NT SYSTEM account would have no way of knowing which account was the active one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems:

- The immediate, technical problem: `The system cannot find the file specified` implies that the specified [KNOWNFOLDERID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/knownfolderid) GUID is not recognized.

  - That said, among your two GUIDs it is `{7d83ee9b-2244-4e70-b1f5-5393042af1e4}`, not the one mentioned in your error message, `{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}` (the Downloads folder), that is unknown.
- A conceptual problem: You're trying to call [`SHSetKnownFolderPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shsetknownfolderpath) for *specific users*, which requires that you pass a so-called access token representing the user of interest as the `hToken` argument.

  - Since you're passing `0` for `hToken`, you're always updating for the *current* user.

---

If you want to avoid the additional complexity of obtaining access tokens representing other users via the [`LogonUser` WinAPI function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-logonuserw), you can bypass `SHSetKnownFolderPath` calls and write directly to the registry, as your code in part already does; however, note that while that should work as of this writing, doing so is [discouraged](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031103-00/?p=41973) and may at some point in the future stop working.

Comment: apologies I am new to Stack Overflow. It was helpful, but it ended up being moot as my other script which runs as the logged in user and uses user context seems to be working. I will definitely refer to this if I need to perform this function as the SYSTEM account.

Comment: @Wumbowarrior: No worries, thanks for accepting. Glad to hear you found a solution. Actually, in the case at hand you wouldn't use the `LogonUser` function for the SYSTEM account, but to impersonate a _specific user_ (doings so requires admin privileges).